# How to serve data without open a port to listen?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, delphi

I have developed an application that basically serves data from a large database. The clients are mobile applications that pull data from the  customer PC where this server application is running.

The main problem is that the server application must be installed in the customer PCs. There are hundreds of customers, so they need to be able to setup the server application.

My first attempt was to develop a normal server application. When this app starts, it opens a port and listen it. The mobile application only needs to connect to the user IP to get data. It worked fine but this attempt is not a good solution. First of all because each user needs to configure routers, proxies, etc. and in many cases, they are not computer literate. In second place, another developer told me that in 2015, nobody should install apps that open ports in the customer PCs because it is really dangerous. (I was not aware of it).

What I would like is:

1)  Avoid configuring proxies, routers, etc. The customer installation must be really easy.

2)  The mobile application needs to request data to the customer PC. When and what is needed is unknown until the mobile sends the request.

Somebody suggested a polling system, but I am not clear how it works. The customer app would need to ask to the main server each few seconds to be “real-time” and it does not seem viable.

Another person suggested to push data periodically to a main server, and then, the mobile could ask this data to the main server. I cannot push data from customer to our main server I have no idea what the mobile app will need

Which pattern could I follow for my scenario?

Thank you

Comment: You must have an app on the server that is monitoring a port in order to establish the connection from the client. Web (http) servers, for instance, always listen on a port (the default is 80), and a web browser makes a request via http to port 80 at that IP address. You have no choice but to have a server listening somewhere in order to accept the client request. What protocol are you using for communication? If it's a standard one, chances are the port may already be open. (This sounds like something you should have figured out long before writing your app.)

Comment: What you need is open and close specific ports using UPnP with your application. Unfortunately I don't have any source code to provide it to you as an example.

Comment: Skype and Dropbox by default try to open ports on the client computer to accept incoming connections from other clients. These dinosaurs still do not know that we are in 2015 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a scenario could be a use case for message oriented middleware, maybe using a service like CloudAMQP which can be accessed with applications in many programming languages.

The mobile device can then send a request to the CloudAMQP server, which will be received by the user / customer server. Both are clients from the CloudAMQP message broker perspective. The customer server delivers the requested data to the CloudAMQP server, and in turn will be set to the mobile device.

For such a request/response communication style over message oriented middleware, there are standard solutions available, for example temporary queues: the mobile device connects, and creates a destination queue on the AMQP server which only exists for the duration of the connection. Then every request can use the temp queue as reply address for the customer server. The customer server picks up the requests, generates a response, and sends it to the given reply address. Examples for RabbitMQ (the message broker behind CloudAMQP) are available on the RabbitMQ home page:

[Remote procedure call (RPC)](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-java.html) (using the Java client, also [available in C#](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-dotnet.html) and other languages)

I have ported the example code to a Delphi demo for the Habari Client for RabbitMQ library (which I am the author of).

Note that CloudAMQP is only one option to host a message broker. You can host a message broker (RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, Apollo...) of course in your own system. These free open source message broker are production ready, and your clients do not have to open ports for incoming connections.

Comment: How the customer server is aware that CloudAMQP has a request from mobile app? Does it need to check CloudAMQP status periodically?

Comment: @DabielKabuto the customer server initiates a TCP connection to CloudAMQP, subscribes to a destination (message queue) and then waits (typically in a background thread) for incoming data. CloudAMQP will then send any message from the device which is adressed to this destination to the TCP socket of the customer server. No periodic check is required, as the TCP socket is bidirectional, CloudAMQP is able to send data over it to the customer server.